# IIS Changing Error Page Responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC application that is running on IIS.  I have created a custom exception filter handler that returns a custom JSON object.  When I run it locally everything works correctly.

However, when I deploy it to IIS the correct HTTP Status Code is returned, but instead of getting my custom JSON object, I am getting a plain text response that says "Bad Request" or "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

In my web config, I have added:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

and

```
<httpErrors>
  <clear />
</httpErrors>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  I needed to add errorMode = "Detailed to my httpErrors tag.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
  <clear />
</httpErrors>
```